# How to use v-bind without showing all the properties as HTML attributes?

Tags: vuejs2

The standard way of passing properties to a component is to use the `v-bind` directive:

```
<Child :prop1="myObj.prop1" :prop2="myObj.prop2" :prop3="myObj.prop3"/>
```

But Vue makes it possible to simply pass the entire object:

```
<Child v-bind="myObj"/>
```

However, one downside I've come across is that the HTML element shows all these properties:

```
<div class="child" prop1="[Object object]" prop2="2" prop3="[1,2,3]">...<div/>
```

Is there a way to prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to avoid this without passing props explicitly:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Non-Prop-Attributes

add `inheritAttrs: false` to the component you are passing props to

Answer (score 1):

After reading documentation on component props look's like vueJs does not provided such provision to avoid this. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html